# What does Google mean by "If you regularly forward email, including using mailing lists or inbound gateways"

Tags: email, gmail

In Google's new "[Email sender guidelines](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126)" It says

> If you regularly forward email, including using mailing lists or inbound gateways, add ARC headers to outgoing email. ARC headers indicate the message was forwarded and identify you as the forwarder. Mailing list senders should also add a List-id: header, which specifies the mailing list, to outgoing messages

**Qeustion 1**

I am using a third party marketing email sender service. How do I know if I am regularly forwarding email or not?

**Question 2**

How do I know if my email has correct ARC headers?